# How to get nested relationship entities with nested subqueries SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have these 4 tables: Scorecard, Section, Topic, Answer.

Each scorecard can have many sections. Each Section can have many topics and each Topic can have many answers.

I am looking to retrieve the data in the following form. Get all sections where scorecard id is equal to to a certain id i do this by left joining and it works so far. Then for each section I want to get of all it's topics and answers as well.

=> Expected Output

```
[{section1, 
topics:[{topicName, answers:[{answerName}]}]}, 
{section2, 
topics:[{topicName, answers:[{answerName}]}]}]
```

I made adjustments to my query and joint the tables correctly but the output data is not correctly organized as I was It to be.

Query:

```
    SELECT sec."id",
       sec."name" AS "sectionName",
       to_json(topics) as "topics"
       
FROM "scorecard" sc 
LEFT JOIN "section" sec ON sc."id" = sec."scorecardId"
LEFT JOIN  (SELECT tp.*, to_json(answers.*) as "answers"
            FROM "topic" tp
            LEFT JOIN (SELECT ans."name" as "answerName", ans."topicId"
            FROM "answer" ans) answers ON answers."topicId" = tp."id"
            ) topics
            ON topics."sectionId" = sec."id"
WHERE sc."id" = $1
```

The current output:

```
    [  id: 85,
      sectionName: 'Consultation',
      topics: {
        id: 109,
        name: 'Was the information correct?',
        answers: [{ answerName: 'Yes', topicId: 109 },        answers: { answerName: 'NO', topicId: 109 }
]
      },
      id: 85,
      sectionName: 'Consultation',
      topics: {
        id: 109,
        name: 'Was the information correct?',
        answers: { answerName: 'NO', topicId: 109 }
      }]
```

My expected output:

```
[  {id: 85,
  sectionName: 'Consultation',
  topics: [{
    id: 109,
    name: 'Was the information correct?',
    answers: [{ answerName: 'Yes', topicId: 109 },
             { answerName: 'NO', topicId: 109 }]
  }]
} ]
```

I have also tried JOINING all entites as such:

```
SELECT sec."id",
       sec."name" AS "sectionName",
       tp."name" AS topics, ans."name" AS answers
FROM "scorecard" sc 
LEFT JOIN "section" sec ON sc."id" = sec."scorecardId"
LEFT JOIN "topic" tp ON tp."sectionId" = sec."id"
LEFT JOIN "answer" ans ON ans."topicId"= tp."id"
WHERE sc."id" = $1
```

Output is not organized as it should be.

```
[
 {
    id: 91,
    sectionName: 'Politeness',
    topics: 'Was the agent polite with the client?',
    answers: 'No'
  },
  {
    id: 91,
    sectionName: 'Politeness',
    topics: 'Was the agent polite with the client?',
    answers: 'Not everytime'
  },
  {
    id: 91,
    sectionName: 'Politeness',
    topics: 'Was the agent polite with the client?',
    answers: 'Yes'
  }
]
```

Comment: Do you expect JSON-formatted output? The query you have provided as example (regardless of the joins performed) can only output sets of rows (and each row will be (id,name,topics))

Comment: Preferrably JSON. I guess I can to_json(topics) from the first SELECT statement If I am correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join all four tables to get your result.

```
SELECT sec."id",
       sec."name" AS "sectionName",
       tp."name" AS topics, ans."name" AS answers
FROM "scorecard" sc 
LEFT JOIN "section" sec ON sc."id" = sec."scorecardId"
LEFT JOIN "topic" tp on tp."sectionId" = sec."id"
LEFT JOIN "answer" ans on ans."topicId"=tp."id"
WHERE sc."id" = 30
```

Thanks @Luuk for creating the dbfiddle link.

```
  select json_agg(x) AS result
  from 
  (
    SELECT sec."id",
        sec."name" AS "sectionName",
        json_agg(topics) as "topics"
        
   FROM "scorecard" sc 
   LEFT JOIN "section" sec ON sc."id" = sec."scorecardId"
   LEFT JOIN  (SELECT tp.id,tp.name,tp."sectionId", json_agg(answers.*) as "answers"
             FROM "topic" tp
             LEFT JOIN (SELECT ans."name" as "answerName", ans."topicId"
             FROM "answer" ans) answers ON answers."topicId" = tp."id"
             group by tp.id,tp.name,tp."sectionId"
             ) topics
             ON topics."sectionId" = sec."id"
   WHERE sc."id" = 85
   group by sec."id", sec."name"
 )x
```

Output:

| result |
| --- |
| [{"id":85,"sectionName":"Consulation","topics":[{"id":109,"name":"Was the information correct?","sectionId":85,"answers":[{"answerName":"Yes","topicId":109}, <br> {"answerName":"NO","topicId":109}]}]}] |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=98e94a6559adcb0e233df4488fc30f04)*149)*

Comment: I have tried this before posting but it is not what I am looking. It is returns duplicate sections on each topic."sectionId" = section."id" match

Comment: @charleslenx I have revised my answer. It's what you are looing for.

Comment: @charleslenx You are most welcome. Best wishes.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a `JOIN` condition to the table `topics`

```
SELECT sec."id",
       sec."name" AS "sectionName",
       topics
FROM "scorecard" sc 
LEFT JOIN "section" sec ON sc."id" = sec."scorecardId"
LEFT JOIN (SELECT tp.* 
      FROM "topic" tp 
      WHERE tp."sectionId" = sec."id"
           (SELECT tp.* 
            FROM "topic" tp 
            WHERE tp."sectionId" = sec."id"
           )
      ) as topics  ON topics.??? = ???  -- Here you should enter the relation
                                        --  from topics to your section.
WHERE sc."id" = 30
```

EDIT:

With you (current) input I creates this [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=16d239143af262d8cf977992e07b4651)

The output:

```
[
    {
        "id": 85,
        "sectionName": "Consulation",
        "topics": {
            "id": 109,
            "name": "Was the information correct?",
            "sectionId": 85,
            "answers": {
                "answerName": "Yes",
                "topicId": 109
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 85,
        "sectionName": "Consulation",
        "topics": {
            "id": 109,
            "name": "Was the information correct?",
            "sectionId": 85,
            "answers": {
                "answerName": "NO",
                "topicId": 109
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: Thank you for the input. I adjusted it accordingly because in your query we are selecting the topic twice without the answer. But I am still getting the same syntax error.

Comment: I did not notice this part: `(SELECT tp.* FROM "topic" tp WHERE tp."sectionId" = sec."id" )` of your query which should be changed in the same way.  That piece is causing the error, and I am not sure what you are trying to do there..... Maybe you should read this [tutorial](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-joins/) about how to create a JOIN ?

Comment: I fixed my joints. They are okay now. But the output is not as expected and they are not being organized as an array per joins. I updated my post you can see the current output

Comment: I added a DBFIDDLE, but was not able to reproduce your problem. (I must have made some wrong guesses.... )

Comment: Thank you Luuk for the fiddle and your insights.